# Video getting uploaded to firebase storage but the url is not getting uploaded to cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload videos to firebase storage and the firebase storage url to firestore . The video is getting stored to firebase storage but I am unable to get url in cloud firestone database.
I am picking video using imagepicker, which is also getting picked.

Upload button :

```
List<File> _video = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add video'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                uploading = true;
              });

              uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
            },
```

Uploadfile :

```
Future uploadFile() async {
   
 int i = 1;

    for (var vid in _video) {
      setState(() {
        val = i / _video.length;
      });
      
      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('videos/${Path.basename(vid.path)}');
      await ref!.putFile(vid).whenComplete(() async {
       
        await ref!.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          vidRef!.add({
            'url': value
          }); 
          i++; 
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    vidRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
        'Videourls'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you `print(ref!.getDownloadURL())` inside the `getDownloadURL` callback, does it print a value?

Comment: Yes it is printing, I checked the link, it is correct too

Comment: So I realized it is working for some videos but not other videos. I don't understand why?